# How to encode token using curl

Tags: php, curl

***STEP - 1***

I am sending a xml request using CURL and its returning "**TOKEN**" to me. Please find the below code here:

```
<root><request><type>mykey</type><username>myusername</username><password>mypassword</password></request></root>

$curl_handle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);// passing API URL here
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_strign); // passing xml as a string
$result = curl_exec ($curl_handle);
```

In this above code executing fine and returning **Token** as a result.

***STEP - 2***

In second step, I have to send above token to get my result but not getting result.Please find the below code:

```
$xml = "<root>
<request>
<type>myparam</type>
<token>lGcvdOnetuxK0paE+AIxE93GB85DURIpOeoBw8quqOs=</token>
</request>
</root>";

curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
$result = curl_exec ($curl_handle);
curl_close ($curl_handle);
print_r($result);
```

May be this Token is contains special charter as i guess, so that I am not getting result. I have seen console url response status in browser its 200 ok.

I do appreciate advance for your help.

Comment: What is the API you're interacting with? You should consult the API docs to see the format of the data you should send. I doubt it's an XML string.

Comment: Yes,As per there documents, we need to send request as a XML format

Comment: Neil, I agree with xiankai. You need to consult the $curl_url service and see if you comply with the request data, or if there is something else wrong. Remember also that some apps may send an error message (eg. 'Incorrect password') with a 200 header, meaning this is a valid response (from a browser perspective) even though the from the application perpsective it is an error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a problem with your post data. You should read details about CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS here :

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-setopt.php

So your xml variable should probably be defined like this:

```
$xml = array("token" => "lGcvdOnetuxK0paE+AIxE93GB85DURIpOeoBw8quqOs");
```

At least it should be an array.